# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs:

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I want to run a Process with Bash. I uploaded the jar file, I have checked my `.conf` and shell files. In general this process is meant to write in a database table, and not in a hdfs path.

I don't know if I need to add in the code an additional hdfs path before generating the jar. Next I show some part of the exception:

```
22/09/07 21:50:42 INFO yarn.Client: Deleted staging directory hdfs://nn/user/srv_remozo_equip/.sparkStaging/application_1661633254168_93772
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://nn:8020/applications/recup_remozo_equipos/Logistica_Carga_Input_SimpleData/logistica_carga_input_simpledata_2.11-0.1.jar
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1757)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:386)
```

I dont know where the exception is coming from, or if related to the .conf and shell files.

Next i share some part of the code(some paths and names are in spanish), where it is the logic and writes in database.

// ================= INICIO LÓGICA DE PROCESO =================
//Se crea df a partir de archivo diario input de acuerdo a la ruta indicada
val df_csv = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("sep",";").option("mode","dropmalformed").load("/applications/recup_remozo_equipos/equipos_por_recuperar/output/agendamientos_sin_pet_2")

```
  val df_final = df_csv.select($"RutSinDV".as("RUT_SIN_DV"),
    $"dv".as("DV"),
    $"Agendado".as("AGENDADO"),
    to_date(col("Dia_Agendado"), "yyyyMMdd").as("DIA_AGENDADO"),
    $"Horario_Agendado".as("HORARIO_AGENDADO"),
    $"Nombre_Agendamiento".as("NOMBRE_AGENDAMIENTO"),
    $"Telefono_Agendamiento".as("TELEFONO_AGENDAMIENTO"),
    $"Email".substr(0,49).as("EMAIL"),
    $"Region_Agendamiento".substr(0,29).as("REGION_AGENDAMIENTO"),
    $"Comuna_Agendamiento".as("COMUNA_AGENDAMIENTO"),
    $"Direccion_Agendamiento".as("DIRECCION_AGENDAMIENTO"),
    $"Numero_Agendamiento".substr(0,5)as("NUMERO_AGENDAMIENTO"),
    $"Depto_Agendamiento".substr(0,9).as("DEPTO_AGENDAMIENTO"),
    to_timestamp(col("fecha_registro")).as("FECHA_REGISTRO"),
    to_timestamp(col("Fecha_Proceso")).as("FECHA_PROCESO")
  )
  // ================== FIN LÓGICA DE PROCESO ==================

  // Limpieza en EXADATA
  println("[INFO] Se inicia la limpieza por reproceso en EXADATA")

  val query_particiones = "(SELECT * FROM (WITH DATA AS (select table_name,partition_name,to_date(trim('''' " +
    "from regexp_substr(extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select high_value from all_tab_partitions " +
    "where table_name='''|| table_name|| ''' and table_owner = '''|| table_owner|| ''' and partition_name = '''" +
    "|| partition_name|| ''''),'//text()'),'''.*?''')),'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') high_value_in_date_format " +
    "FROM all_tab_partitions WHERE table_name = '" + table_name + "' AND table_owner = '" + table_owner + "')" +
    "SELECT partition_name FROM DATA WHERE high_value_in_date_format > DATE '" + startDateYear + "-" + startDateMonth + "-" + startDateDay + "' " +
    "AND high_value_in_date_format <= DATE '" + endDateYear + "-" + endDateMonth + "-" + endDateDay + "') A)"

  Class.forName(driver_jdbc)
  val db = DriverManager.getConnection(url_jdbc, user_jdbc, pass_jdbc)
  val st = db.createStatement()

  try {
    val consultaParticiones = spark.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("url", url_jdbc)
      .option("driver", driver_jdbc)
      .option("dbTable", query_particiones)
      .option("user", user_jdbc)
      .option("password", pass_jdbc)
      .load()
      .collect()
    for (partition <- consultaParticiones) {
      st.executeUpdate("call " + table_owner + ".DO_THE_TRUNCATE_PARTITION('" + table + "','" + partition.getString(0) + "')")
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      println("[ERROR TRUNCATE] " + e)
  }

  st.close()
  db.close()

  println("[INFO] Se inicia la inserción en EXADATA")

  df_final.filter($"DIA_AGENDADO" >= "2022-08-01")
    .repartition(repartition).write.mode("append")
    .jdbc(url_jdbc, table, utils.jdbcProperties(driver_jdbc, user_jdbc, pass_jdbc))

  println("[INFO] Inserción en EXADATA completada con éxito")
  println("[INFO] Proceso Logistica Carga Input SimpleData")
```

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to execute which is resulting in this error.

Comment: The exception was resolved. It was because in the shell file, in the final part where it calls the location of the jar file, that path, although I had checked it, had a very subtle difference in one character, so I copied and pasted that path. Important to know for a next occasion, just copy and paste.